# how to loop with dynamic commands on each button

Tags: loops, tkinter, button, lambda, dynamic

I´m trying change the button command while create into a loop.
Use this for change value in database control, but the button is not change.

the especific code:

```
    camposDinamicosBE[i].configure(command=lambda baixaBTN=i:[ buildGerarBaixa(prodID='1')])
    print(f'comando {i}= ',camposDinamicosBE[i].cget('command'))
```

the error :

All commands showing the last i value (in my case 36) , but the print command to undestand whats is happening allways show random numbers and i cant see whats happening.
the print(f'comando {i}= ',camposDinamicosBE[i].cget('command')) is showing:

.
.
.

```
comando 34=  1409460431232<lambda>
comando 35=  1409460432832<lambda>
comando 36=  1409460416256<lambda
```

but command prompt when press button is showing allways: 36

partial code that give the problem:

```
for i in range(0, campos):
           
           
                                
        label_box = Label(frame_aba1,text=valores[i]["produto"],font=('Calibri 8 bold     '),bg='#D8D8D8')
        entry_box = Entry(frame_aba1,width=15,font=('Calibri 8     '),name='entry_'+str(variavel.lower()))
        entry_boxPd = Entry(frame_aba1,width=15,font=('Calibri 8     '),name='entry_'+str(variavelPD.lower()),bg='peachpuff',fg='indianred')
        label_atual = Label(frame_aba1,text='0',font=('Calibri 10 bold     '),bg='#D8D8D8',fg='blue',anchor='n',justify='center',height=1)
        #here is the problem
        baixaBTN = Button(frame_aba1, text =f"",font=('Calibri 11 bold '),command= lambda baixaBTN=i:[ buildGerarBaixa(prodID='f{i}')], bg =cinzaClaro,anchor='e')
  
      if(i-1<=math.ceil(campos/2)):
                 
            linha=0
            lin=i
            label_box.place(x=linha+100, y=100+(22*lin))
            entry_box.place(x=linha+400, y=100+(22*lin),height=17,width=40)
            entry_boxPd.place(x=linha+450, y=100+(22*lin),height=17,width=40)
            label_atual.place(x=linha+500, y=100+(22*lin))
            baixaBTN.place(x = linha+70, y = 100+(22*lin),width = 22,height=20)`
```

I've tried everything I found here on the forum and on Google, but the buttons don't work. Everything else is working 100%

What I would like is for the buttons to be created in the loop next to each listed item and when clicked it calls a specific function passing the id of the clicked button. This way I could manage the item in the bank individually, such as activating, deactivating, changing the value...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPhIs.jpg)

Comment: ways that i tried:

comDinamico[i]=partial(buildGerarBaixa,prodID=f'{i}')

baixaBTN = Button(frame_aba1, text =f"",font=('Calibri 11 bold '),command= comDinamico[i], bg =cinzaClaro,anchor='e')


and the output of print(comDinamico):

{0: functools.partial(<function buildGerarBaixa at 0x000001CDA486E310>, prodID='0'), 1: functools.partial(<function buildGerarBaixa at 0x000001CDA486E310>, prodID='1'), 
2: functools.partial(<function buildGerarBaixa at 0x000001CDA486E310>, prodID='2'),...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution that worked perfectly and I'm posting it in case other people need it too. I still don't know why the print came out with those random numbers followed by  when the result was always the same and if someone could explain it would be great, but this already solves my problem for now.

I now need to figure out how to create a link in the label and give it a command, but if someone can answer here, it would be great. If I can't due to the forum rules, I will understand. Anyway, here's the solution:

```
my_str = tk.StringVar()
l1 = tk.Label(my_w,  textvariable=my_str, width=10 )
l1.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=5) 

def show_lan(my_language):
    my_str.set(my_language)

list_languages = ("PHP","Python","HTML","Tkinter")
var = 0


for language in list_languages:
    btn = tk.Button(my_w, text=language, command=lambda 
lan=language:show_lan(lan))
btn.grid(row=1,column=var)
var += 1
```

the solution was founded here: https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-button-dynamic.php